# JSF fails to filter or sort a rich:column when the column is included as a custom tag

Tags: jsf, jstl, richfaces

Using MyFaces 1.2.12 and Rich Faces 3.3.3 I have a repeating pattern of rich:columns like this:

```
    <rich:column label="my column name"
                 sortable="true"
                 selfSorted="true"
                 sortBy="#{entity.attribute}"
                 filterBy="#{entity.attribute}"
                 filterEvent="onkeyup">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="my column name"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{entity.attribute}"/>
    </rich:column>
```

The column name and `entity.attribute` change for each column. The filtering and sorting work correctly.

However, the repetition for each column is tedious so I've tried to replace it with a custom tag `mytags:filterableSortableColumn`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <!--@elvariable id="label" type="java.lang.String"-->
    <!--@elvariable id="item" type="java.lang.Object"-->
    <rich:column label="#{label}"
                 sortable="true"
                 sortBy="#{item}"
                 selfSorted="true"
                 filterBy="#{item}"
                 filterEvent="onkeyup">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{label}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
    </rich:column>
</ui:composition>
```

Used like this:

```
<mytags:filterableSortableColumn label="my column name" item="#{entity.attribute}"/>
```

This works for data display and column header, but when using the datatable for filtering or sorting I get an exception (from hibernate, incidentally):

`Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [#{item] on this ManagedType [com.example.entity.Entity]`

The `[#{item]` should have been resolved before then.

Is this something I've failed to account for in the interaction between a table and it's columns perhaps?